# Recursive lookup needed. DB vs. C# GUI

Tags: c#, sql, database, recursion, recursive-query

I currently have a program in which I want to list 'support tickets' in a grid.

The tickets are coming from a SQL DB out of a ticketing system.

A ticket has an activity, example:

[image]

I have a fully functional design but have a problem to list the following:

What I want to do in my program is to list the parent tickets, with their child tickets as children (details). However, with the added complexity, i'm obliged to do this recursively.

Example:

[image]

My questions were:

- In this case, is the recursive lookup to be done on DB level? Or application level?
- AM i obliged to achieve this, to loop through all the tickets PER TICKET?
- How is performance affected by these look ups?

I did some research and tried to get the tickets alone but haven't achieved this. I tried it on the level of the DB using:

```
SELECT ticketID,
FROM dbo.Ticket
UNION ALL

SELECT a.ticketID, 
FROM dbo.Ticket a 
INNER JOIN dbo.ticket s ON a.ticketID = s.ticketID 

SELECT * FROM Ticket 
where ticketID = 1
```

While I was testing this, i had the idea that maybe I'm doing this wrong, since maybe, the recursive search is better to be done in my application level (in which i would just need to do a simple `select * from ticket` in my DB.

Is this true? Would I be needing to do this on application level?

Comment: Usually presentation layer frameworks provide ootb controls that handle hierarchical data. Depending on your RDBMS version, you *could* consider using queries returning Xml or Json but that depends on your implementation. Subjectively I'd recommend selecting a flat result of tickets.

Comment: It's unclear if you want to show all tickets in the databade, or just all ticketa that belong to the same parent. If it's the fitst, do the recursive match in the application. If it's the second, a recutsive cte will probably be a better choise, because then you can select only the data you actually need.

Comment: sounds like you want CTE    ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL )

Comment: I would do it on the application level, much easier to read in my opinion. `Ticket` has a collection of `Ticket` object

Comment: why's this getting voted for close?

Comment: this is not too broad, it has a very specific answer the OP couldn't work out the SQL query so wondered if it had to be done by application code, but there IS a very specific way to handle it in SQL

Comment: @KeithNicholas It's definitely not too broad, but it *could* be considered subjective as the OP not only asks *how* but also *if* recursion should be handled by the DB query.

Comment: IMHO It's not too broad, nor it is subjective - It lacks information. So I repeat the question in my first comment: @User3127554: Do you want to show all the tickets in your tree view, or only all the tickets that belongs to a single ancestor? The answer to this question will give you the answer to your original question: If you want all the tickets anyway, then select all of them from the database and do the construction of the tree view in your application code. If you want only a single ancestor and all it's decedents, use a recursive cte to get only the relevant tickets from your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a recursive query in SQL Server

Given

[image]

```
With TicketTree(tID,  pID)
As
(
    Select ticketID, parentID From Ticket Where ticketID = 1 
    UNION ALL
    Select ticketID, parentID from Ticket Inner join TicketTree R On parentID = R.tID   
)
select * from TicketTree
```

gives

[image]

or if you query root ticket 4

[image]

You can then join with your Activity or whatever you want to do, I just kept it to the minimum need for a recursive query

Comment: as you can see, they are screen shots straight from sql management studio

Comment: thanks! but at what point would i have to update the linked table and select its children? wouldn't I be obliged to do this in my program and not in the db? this because i would have to enumerate for each row and wouldn't be knowing what the `WHERE` clause would have.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it's the optimal approach, but I'd write a stored procedure and have it simply get all the relevant tickets at the database level.  I mean, you could easily have a stored procedure loop through until it's gotten all the children/parents of a particular ticket, and return all those records back to the client.

A possible way of doing this:

1. Create an empty table that contains the records you're going to pass
   back
2. Create a table for "IDs to look for next"
3. Query your specific ticket
4. Add the results to your return table, and the ID to the Lookfor-ID
   table
5. While there are still results in the "Lookfor" table

   ```
   Query the DB for anything that has a child or parent in the Lookfor Table
       (and that isn't already in the return table)
   Add all those records to the return table
   Clear out the "Lookfor" table, and add all those new IDs to it.
   ```

Anyway, yeah, you'd still have to assemble the data correctly on the C# end, but you wouldn't be hitting the DB with a bunch of separate queries.  The stored proc would get you all the records you're interested in with one swoop.